# Allow Incoming Google Notifications Based on Source, Reject Fake attemtps

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, push-notification, gmail

Google or any push notification service generally send notifications on an open route shared while subscription.

I have gmail/drive/calendar push notifications provisioned on an express server but when I check incoming push notification req.headers I don't see origin or referer.

**Question**: How do I know incoming request is coming from Google and somebody else is not sending fake notifications?

Currently logging `req` or `req.headers` do not show `origin` or `referer`.

I see for drive/calendar we can set token field and expect the same in return but is there a generic way to have a whitelist.